# Jenkins 2 Git Webhook "No valid crumb was included in the request"

Tags: git, jenkins, github, webhooks

I have created a Jenkins 2 instance and have configured it read a Git repo every time an update is pushed. The linking between the two seems to work fine, however I am getting a Cross Site Request Forgery issue.

It mentions in the error log that it needs a valid crumb, however I cannot seem to find a way for Github Webhooks to provide this to Jenkins.

Git
Payload URL: http://jenkins_username:jenkins_password@host:8080/webhook/

Secret: jenkins access token